# Javascript RegEx assertion

Tags: javascript, regex, assert

I have this example:

`/(?=\d)(?=[a-z])/.test("3a")` which returns `false` 
but this 
`/(?=\d)(?=.*[a-z])/.test("3a")` works.

Can you explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me break down what you are doing:

```
Test string = test("3a")
```

Example 1: `/(?=\d)(?=[a-z])/`

`(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead that the next character is a digit
`(?=[a-z])` is a positive lookahead that the next character is in range a-z

This is impossible and will always return false as it is asserting that the next character is both a-z and a digit which it cannot be.

Example 2: `/(?=\d)(?=.*[a-z])/`

`(?=\d)` is a positive lookahead that the next character is a digit
`(?=.*[a-z])` is a positive lookahead that anywhere in your string after where match starts there is a character is in range a-z

This sees `3a` in the test string because starting the match at 3 the next character is a digit and 3a fulfills the `.*[a-z]` assertion.

It may or may not be important to point out that because these are lookaheads you are not actually matching anything. I don't know what it is you are really trying to do.

If you want to test that there is a-z after a digit you can put it into one assertion:
`/(?=\d[a-z])/`

Answer (score 1):

Your first pattern

```
/(?=\d)(?=[a-z])/.test("3a")
```

is asserting that *both* a digit and letter occur *in the same place*.  Obviously, this will never be true.  On the other hand, your second pattern:

```
/(?=\d)(?=.*[a-z])/.test("3a")
```

asserts that a digit occurs, and it also asserts that a single letter occurs anywhere in the string.  This matches for an input of `3a`.

Comment: This: /(?=\d)(?=\w)/.test("3a") doesnt this mean asserting  both a digit and letter occur in the same place? But it works.

Comment: @Nick If that works it must mean that `\w` includes digits.  In other words, you sort of asserted the same thing.

Comment: \w doesnt include digits. Only words.

Comment: @Nick Yes, `\w` [does include numbers as well as letters](http://rextester.com/VQVDQ77462).